# Where in Oracle APEX interface I put this code?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

This link explains how to show an image from a BLOB in a table, to a Display image item
http://www.apexninjas.com/blog/2011/09/uploading-and-displaying-images-in-apex/

It advises to write this code (the code converts BLOB data into HTML):

```
create or replace PROCEDURE image(image_id IN NUMBER)
AS
 l_mime        VARCHAR2 (255);
 l_length      NUMBER;
 l_file_name   VARCHAR2 (2000);
 lob_loc       BLOB;

BEGIN
       SELECT i.MIME_TYPE, i.CONTENT, DBMS_LOB.getlength (i.CONTENT), i.FILENAME
       INTO l_mime, lob_loc, l_length, l_file_name
       FROM EMP_IMAGE i
       WHERE i.ID = image_id;  

       OWA_UTIL.mime_header (NVL (l_mime, 'application/octet'), FALSE);
       htp.p('Content-length: ' || l_length);
       htp.p('Content-Disposition:  filename="' || SUBSTR(l_file_name, INSTR(l_file_name, '/') + 1) || '"');
       owa_util.http_header_close;
       wpg_docload.download_file(Lob_loc);
END image;
```

I'm new to Oracle APEX 5, and I do not understand where in the interface should I write that code

My UI loos like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ck9Up.png

Answer (score 1):

They're telling you to create that procedure in the database; it's not an APEX component. I don't think I would recommend their approach of opening a security hole to allow direct execution of a custom local procedure. And it's not necessary anymore; APEX has changed a lot since 2011.

On the left, click your Display Image item named "IMAGE". Then on the right, under "Settings", change the "Based On" to **BLOB Column returned by a SQL Statement**, and just put a query in there that'll return the column you want.

You'll need a primary key to find the right row; here I'm assuming that you're using the FILE_NAME page item, but probably a better option would be to have a hidden page item to hold the primary key from your IMAGES table, maybe called "P1_ID" for an "id" column, and add `RETURNING id INTO :P1_ID` to the end of your INSERT statement in your page process. Then your "IMAGE" page item query will look something like:

```
SELECT i.CONTENT
   FROM IMAGES i
   WHERE i.ID = :P1_ID;
```

Comment: The problem with "BLOB Column returned by a SQL Statement" is that it cannot be dynamically updated. It only loads once, and not even a refresh Dynamic action or Set Value can change the image displayed.